# change attribute for same componet when I override onclick() method

Tags: java, wicket

I am using apache wicket for the follwoing page :

what I want to achieve is when I click on the link I change an attribute from (aria-extended = false to true and vice versa);

I succeed to add CSS that changes when we click, but this is for the child component.
why I cannot do the same for the same component I am overriding (the method does not work is addAria())

```
  private AjaxFallbackLink<Void> createTogglableLink() {
     final String name = holding.getName();
     final Label nameLabel = new Label("nameLabel", name);
     nameLabel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
     addCssClass(nameLabel);
    AjaxFallbackLink<Void> togglableLink = new AjaxFallbackLink<Void>("togglableLink") {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1191922367898057679L;

    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        this.add( new AttributeModifier("aria-expanded", true, new Model<>("true")));
        final ChildVisibility visibility;
        if (childContainer.isVisible()) {
            visibility = ChildVisibility.COLLAPSED;
        } else {
            visibility = ChildVisibility.EXPANDED;
            if (holding.isExpandable()) {
                try {
                    holding = localOESearchService.expandHolding(externalId, arenaMemberId, cardPinBean, getLocale(), holding);
                } catch (RecordNotFoundException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Could not expand holding when record with external ID = '" + externalId + "' and ArenaMember ID = '" + arenaMemberId
                            + "' could not be found", e);
                    addErrorMessage("msgNoHoldingsDueToRecordNotFound", externalId.getValue(), holdingFeedback);
                    if (target != null) {
                        target.addComponent(holdingFeedback);
                    }
                }
                List<? extends IHolding> children = holding.getChildren();
                childView.setList(children);
            }
        }
        childContainer.setVisible(visibility.isVisible());
        holding.setChildVisibility(visibility);
        // The status should only be visible when the child holdings are not expanded
        statusLabel.setVisible(!childContainer.isVisible());
        addCssClass(nameLabel);
        addAria(this);

        if (target != null) {
            target.addComponent(childContainer);
            target.addComponent(statusLabel);
            target.addComponent(nameLabel);
        }
    }


togglableLink.add(nameLabel);
StringResourceModel togglableResourceModel = new StringResourceModel("selectToViewHoldings", this, new Model<>(holding));
togglableLink.add(new AttributeModifier("aria-controls", true, new Model<>(this.childContainer.getMarkupId())));
togglableLink.add(new AttributeModifier("aria-label", true, togglableResourceModel));
togglableLink.add(new AttributeModifier("title", true, togglableResourceModel));
return togglableLink;}


private Label addCssClass(Label nameLabel) {
Model<String> cssModel = holding.isLastHolding() ? CSS_END_OF_HOLDINGS : childContainer.isVisible() ? CSS_EXPANDED : CSS_COLLAPSED;
AttributeModifier cssModifier = new AttributeModifier("class", true, cssModel);
nameLabel.add(cssModifier);
return nameLabel;}

private Component addAria(Component component) {
Model<String> ariaExpandedModel = holding.isLastHolding() ? ARIA_COLLAPSED : childContainer.isVisible() ? ARIA_COLLAPSED : ARIA_EXPANDED;
AttributeModifier ariaExpandedModifier = new AttributeModifier("aria-expanded", true, ariaExpandedModel);
component.add(ariaExpandedModifier);
return component;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `#onComponentTag()` instead of `AttributeModifier`. In `#onClick()` just set the new value for the attribute:

```
AjaxFallbackLink<Void> togglableLink = new AjaxFallbackLink<Void>("togglableLink") {

   private boolean ariaExtended = false; 

   @Override
   public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
      ariaExtended = !ariaExtended;
      target.add(this);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
      tag.put("aria-expanded", "" + ariaExtended);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but after the click the attribute does not change,
I would like to change the value after the clicking

Comment: Right! I've forgotten to call `target.add(this);` in onClick().